# When to use "assign" in smarty?

Tags: smarty, assign

What is the difference between line #1 and line #2? Both are stored in **template.tpl** and both are working identically. Why should I use {assign} if  direct assignment (line #2) works as well.

```
Line #1  {assign var=page value="1"}
Line #2  {$page = 1}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which ever you prefer however Line#1 allows you to specify the `scope` (parent, root, global) and you can flag the variable as `nocache`, which is very useful for the very rare occasions when you need to add logic to the presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks Tristan for clarifying it for me.